# Persisting values

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

I am working on a project where I have to save some values that are being entered by users. Is that possible? How/Where can I do that? I have been searching on google and have not found anything relevant.

Comment: you can do an ontology write back to persist values input by a user in a form.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly you are using Contour. I am not sure about Contour, but in Quiver you can write back to the Ontology using [Actions](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/action-types/overview/).

Unfortunately I don't know for certain if that can be applied to your use-case, but I think so.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture data from users in many ways. Which one is the best primarily depends on the user workflow.

Some examples:
Foundry Forms - You can create a form that the user will put the information into. You can even pre-populate parts of the form depending on where the user is coming from.
Workshop module - Using actions from a workshop module enables you to capture any data and store it directly into the ontology layer
Slate - Any input into a slate app can be written back into a phonograph object

All of these can be written back into a dataset that can further be processed in any other tool in Foundry or used in a different user facing application.

If you describe your workflow a bit more I can recommend a specific approach.